# How to use nested loop for different arrays in laravel blade template?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to display the distance for each of my drivers on my database in my view.

When I do die or dump for `$pickupDistanceAndTime2` it returns the arrays below, so I need each of the drivers to have its own distance.

```php
0 => array:2 [▶]
1 => array:2 [▶]
2 => array:2 [▶]
```

```php
return view('driverspane', [
    'drivers' => $driver,
    'rideDistancenTime' => $pickupDistanceAndTime2,
]);
```

In my view, I am looping but not getting the way I want it to appear.

```php
@foreach ($drivers as $item)
    @foreach ($rideDistancenTime as $data)
        {{ $data[0] }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

But the above code keeps repeating distance and time for each of the driver, but I want each of the driver to have its own distance and time only, please see the result I am getting below attached.
[image]

The array for `$driver` returns

```
#items: array:3 [▼
    0 => App\Driver {#317 ▶}
    1 => App\Driver {#300 ▶}
    2 => App\Driver {#281 ▶}
  ]
```

Comment: How are $drivers data related to $rideDistancenTime? In theory the second one should have an index that put in relation its data with the driver, so the second foreach is like @foreach ($rideDistancenTime as[$item] $data)

Comment: Please update your question to expand the contents of the very first array that you ```dd```ied

Comment: ok let me do that now

Comment: edited please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you did above, you are just repeating the same values for the first index of the array. You should not do a nested `foreach` statement.

Rather you could do it this way(using a `for` statement, provided that the arrays all have same number of keys:

```
 @for ($i=0; $i<count($drivers); $i++)
      
      {{$rideDistancenTime[$i][1]}}
      
@endfor
```

Now it should loop properly.

Comment: let me check with this and get back please

Comment: I made an error. I have edited my answer.

Comment: am i loopin this in the view or controller?

Comment: In your view file.

Comment: Replace the ```foreach```s you had previously.

Comment: Undefined offset: 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248694/discussion-between-innovin-and-midel-group).

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to achieve your goal:

````
$rideDistancenTime;

@foreach ($drivers as $key => $item)
    
      {{ $rideDistancenTime[$key] }}

@endforeach```
````